# TcpClient connection from a web application in Azure to local machine

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web application in Azure which needs to continuously read data from a local machine via `"TcpClient"`.

Can any one please let me know how data can be transmitted between a local machine and a web application in Azure using "`TcpClient`".

Code for TcpClient connection in web application will be like

```
static TcpClient tcpclnt = null;

public Home()
{
    if (tcpclnt == null)
    {
        tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
        tcpclnt.Connect("10.***.***.**", 8***); //10.***.***.** - My PC IP
    }
}
```

Comment: adresses of type 10.xxx.xxx.xxx are private adresses used in [private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), meaning that you can reach it only from your local network. accessing your local machine from internet requires some (not trivial) setup both at network level and on your local machine (e.g. open it firewall in order to allow inbound traffic on some specified port). It's something similar to what you would need to setup a machine on your network as a web server available from the internet

Comment: Search for App Service Hybrid Connections. You'll need to use a hostname, not an IP address as destination but other than that you should be fine. It's trivial to set up.

Comment: Oh i forgot, on top of that, all connectivity is initiated outbound, so no firewall mangling is required. [Here's the relevant doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).